# UPI payment apps not opening on iOS in my PWA

Tags: javascript, ios, progressive-web-apps

I have integrated a payment gateway in my PWA to handle payments. It is working fine until the iframe for the gateway opens. However, when I click on UPI and select an app such as PhonePe, it redirects to homepage of my app. This happens only on iOS and when the app is installed through app store. Works fine when running the website on browser. Haven't been able to find a solution yet. Any ideas where i might be going wrong? Is it a permissions issue or something?

This works fine on android btw

I'm using vue 3 + vite for my App and used PWA Builder to make the PWA.

here is a snippet of my manifest.json Tried changing the display mode to standalone but it didn't help.

```
manifest: {
                
                orientation: "portrait",
                display: "standalone",
                icons: [
                    {
                        src: "/logo/fb_min_logo.png",
                        sizes: "192x192",
                        type: "image/png",
                    },
                    {
                        src: "/logo/fb_min_logo.png",
                        sizes: "683x512",
                        type: "image/png",
                    },
                ],
            },
```